# Which is better: using flags, or pipes?

Tags: unix, tar, pipe, gzip, flag

As with many things in the *nix world, there is more than one way to generate `.tar.gz` files.

Typically, I use the following:

```
tar zcf /path/to/dir.tar.gz /path/to/dir
```

However, I have seen the following as well:

```
tar cf - <files|directories> | gzip -fq9 >/path/to/output.tar.gz
```

Is there a difference between the two?

If so, what is that difference, and does it "matter", or is it merely cosmetic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of specifying `gzip` with a pipe is that you can select options, such as the speed of compression.

In the example you gave, `gzip -fq9` the 9 refers to the *best* and slowest compression.

`q` means 'quiet', and `f` means 'force'. These options are described in the `gzip` man page.